# How to redirect to specific page in FluentSecurity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, fluent-security

Hi I'm using [FluentSecurity](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity) to authenticate and verify users permissions in my MVC application. In the basic settings when a user wants to access to denied `Action` it throws an exception. I want to know how should I redirect to another page (such as login page) instead of showing yellow exception page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question has been answered already but I don't like putting a try catch in every action to handle this situation.

Fluent Security allows you to register a handler for policy violations (see https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki/Policy-violation-handlers).  You have to have a class that inherits from IPolicyViolationHandler.  The convention is to name your class `<PolicyViolationName>PolicyViolationHandler`

Here is an example of a Handler to register a DenyAnonymousAccessPolicyViolationHandler

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom Policy Violation Handler. See http://www.fluentsecurity.net/wiki/Policy-violation-handlers
    /// </summary>
    public class DenyAnonymousAccessPolicyViolationHandler : IPolicyViolationHandler
    {
        public ActionResult Handle(PolicyViolationException exception)
        {
            Flash.Error("You must first login to access that page");
            return new RedirectResult("/");
        }
    }
```

One other caveat that you will run into is that you have to use an IOC container to register these handlers.  I won't debate whether using and IOC container is good or bad but I prefer not to use on if I don't have too.  On their website there was a blog written on how to do this without using an IOC container but I didn't really like that approach as well.  Here is what I did.

```
public static class SecurityConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            SecurityConfigurator.Configure(c =>
                {
                    c.GetAuthenticationStatusFrom(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                    c.GetRolesFrom(() => (HttpContext.Current.Session["Roles"] as string[]));
                        // Blanked Deny All
                    c.ForAllControllers().DenyAnonymousAccess();

                    // Publicly Accessible Areas
                    c.For<LoginController>().Ignore();

                    // This is the part for finding all of the classes that inherit
                    // from IPolicyViolationHandler so you don't have to use an IOC
                    // Container.
                    c.ResolveServicesUsing(type =>
                        {
                            if (type == typeof (IPolicyViolationHandler))
                            {
                                var types = Assembly
                                    .GetAssembly(typeof(MvcApplication))
                                    .GetTypes()
                                    .Where(x => typeof(IPolicyViolationHandler).IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToList();

                                var handlers = types.Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IPolicyViolationHandler).ToList();

                                return handlers;
                            }
                            return Enumerable.Empty<object>();
                        });
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I never use `FluentSecurity` but you can follow this way to redirect in your action. For example;

```
public ActionResult YourActionName()
{
   try
   {

   }
   catch ( Exception )
   {       
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }            
}
```

And also you can use [`HandleError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute on the controller class to catch any unhandled exceptions and it will automatically return the `Error.aspx` view in the Shared folder. Also you can customize it.

For more information, check ScottGu's post.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply but any other built-in feature ?

Comment: take a look to my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Currently [FluentSecurity](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity) stable version(1.4) doesn't have any built-in features to handle `PolicyViolationException`, but you can create a filter to do that, something like this :

```
public class PolicyViolationExceptionHandler : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(PolicyViolationException))
        {
            var routeDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                area = "",
                controller = "account",
                action = "login"
            });

            // Redirect to specific page
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute(routeDictionary);

            // Prevent to handle exceptions
            // Of 'PolicyViolationException' by default filters
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```